# How to register user in AWS Cognito with Phone number otp only

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm working on a mobile app and I want a user to be able to register himself via OTP code only. no password, no email. I use AWS as my cloud infra.
The thing is when I create a new user pool I have to use password and I don't want to use password as I want to authenticate via OTP only.

I have hard time how to configure the user pool for that